# How to use Vue.js inside Nw.js project without bundlers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nwjs

I'm building an application using [NW.js](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/).

I don't want to use any compilers/bundlers etc.

I've installed Vue.js library via npm, and trying to use it via `require`, but it's not being rendered (although, I see console logs that are happening on `created` and `mounted` callbacks, but webpage is blank, and `<div id="app"></div>` is empty.

My code:

- `index.html` (entry point of the nw.js app):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> -->
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">ww</div>
    <script src="/src/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- `app.js` file:

```
// const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js');
// const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.common.prod.js');
// const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.common.js');
// const Vue = require('vue');
const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.js');

const hello = Vue.component('hello', {
  data () {
    return {
      hi: 'Well, hello there!'
    }
  },
  template: '<div>uu {{ hi }}</div>',
  created () {
    console.log('Created!');
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('Mounted!');
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { hello },
  render : h => h(hello),
});
```

As you can see, I've tried various sources of the Vue.js, but none of them made any change - I see both console logs, but nothing gets rendered.

I've made it work only, when I've added Vue.js source via CDN in `index.html` file (you see it commented in the code above) - but how can I use the same file but via local `require()` from `node_modules` ?

As a hack, I can download the contents of the Vue.js file from CDN and load it locally, but I would rather use an npm-based source.

Comment: Inside your `<div id="app">` put your vuejs component with: `<hello></hello>`. This should render the element.

Comment: @Danizavtz thank you for the comment, but it's still not being rendered - I think it's related to vue.js library that is missing template parser part

Answer (score 1):

vue cdn is optimized to be used without the bundlers but when you use the npm version it required bundlers for internals working moreover, try using node integrations settings in nw.js

but still i will prefer you should use the bundlers since these can optimize your build size moreover, you can also use nw plugin provided by vue-cli